# SQL statement problem

Tags: sql, dataset

I have this code:

```
SELECT    idcallhistory3, callid, starttime, answertime, endtime, duration,
          is_answ, is_fail, is_compl, is_fromoutside, mediatype, from_no,
          to_no, callerid, dialednumber, lastcallerid, lastdialednumber,
          group_no, line_no
FROM      "public".callhistory3
WHERE     (starttime >= ?) AND (endtime <= ?) AND (is_fromoutside = ?) 
          AND (from_no = ?) AND (to_no = ?)
```

The problem is I need to pass one value for ? and get all the result without filter, some thing like *

Any help?

Answer (score 7):

```
WHERE 
  (@start is null OR starttime >= @start) AND 
  (@end is null OR endtime <= @end) AND 
  (@fromOutside is null OR is_fromoutside = @fromOutside) AND 
  (@fromNo is null OR from_no = @fromNo) AND 
  (@toNo is null OR to_no = @toNo)
```

Pass nulls for all parameters (dang sql nulls; thanks GC).

Comment: Use "is null" - "= null" is always false because null != null.

Comment: Actually, "= null" should return null.  Whether an unknown equals another unknown is unknown.

Comment: True, but the end effect is the same - that half of the filter statement never takes effect, resulting in null values not matching when they are wanted to match.

Answer (score 3):

I like COALESCE.

You just have to be careful with null values on the left hand side, if there can be nulls on the left hand side you can do something like the last line so that nulls will match.  Typically with anything like this though you will want to make sure your query still performs ok.

```
SELECT    idcallhistory3, callid, starttime, answertime, endtime, duration,
          is_answ, is_fail, is_compl, is_fromoutside, mediatype, from_no,
          to_no, callerid, dialednumber, lastcallerid, lastdialednumber,
          group_no, line_no
FROM      "public".callhistory3
WHERE     (starttime >= COALESCE(@starttime, starttime )) 
          AND (endtime <= COALESCE(@endtime, endtime)) 
          AND (is_fromoutside = COALESCE(@is_fromoutside, is_fromoutside)) 
          AND (from_no = COALESCE(@from_no, from_no)) 
          AND (COALESCE(to_no, -1) = COALESCE(@to_no, to_no, -1)) -- make nulls match
```

Answer (score 2):

For complex queries with multiple optional sections, you may find that it is better to create the SQL to suit. You can do this either at the caller (for example, in C#), or in the database (at least, with SQL Server) - but either way, you *must* ensure it remains parameterised. With the caller doing the work, it is just a case of adding suitable parameters to the command. If the db is generating the TSQL, then the approach depends on the RDBMS. With SQL-Server, `sp_ExecuteSql` is your friend - i.e. you might build a `@cmd` variable based on the query, then:

```
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @cmd, N'@someArg int', @actualArg
```

Where `@someArg` is the declaration inside `@cmd`, and `@actualArg` is the value to pass in at execution time.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way of doing this is something like:

```
WHERE (? IS NULL OR starttime >= ?)
```

and then pass in DBNull.Value. Obviously you need to do this for each parameter you want to be able to "wildcard" like this.

Comment: This is pretty nice, but the "OR" might prevent using indexes on the column. This depends on the specific RDBMS of course.

Comment: leppie: Really? I'd expect any serious database to be able to optimise that incredibly well. It's not exactly a tricky optimisation given that the value of the parameter isn't going to change on each iteration. The left side of the OR will either guarantee a match or can be ignored - query-wide.

Comment: Individually, fine - but in combination (5 in the OP) I have seen this behave very poorly - presumably failing to find an appropriate index.

Comment: I've used this on larger datasets with complex queries with reasonable performance. In MSSQL that is

Comment: Due to parameter sniffing, MS-SQL can initially pick an execution plan appropriate for the initial values - but that is incredibly poor for subsequent runs. I'm not entirely sure that parameter sniffing is an issue with adhoc SQL - but since adhoc query plans are still cached, I'd expect it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Add the "Where" statement conditionally -- only if you need to filter the results

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jamal Hansen.  COALESCE is by far the best performing way to go, at least on SQL Server